# react: использование декоратора для функционального компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, компоненты, декоратор

есть функциональный компонент:

```
const LogChart = (props: IProps_LogChart) => {

    const dbg_timer: number = performance.now();

    // основной код
    console.log(dbg_timer);
}
```

Можно ли сделать декоратор, который бы вычислял `dbg_timer` и добавлял бы результат в `props`?
Что-то из серии:

```
@dbg_timer
const LogChart = (props: IProps_LogChart) => {
    // основной код
    console.log(props.dbg.timer);
}
```

Интересна возможность компактной записи с использованием @

Comment: я писал такую штуку для классов https://www.npmjs.com/package/execution-time-decorators